Matlab code for cumulative area calculation
I have plotted a graph of load and displacment shown below:

The area enclosed within this graph is energy dissipated. I want to know what the area is inside each loop the graph makes. For example, I want the code to return loop 1: area in loop 1, loop 2: area in loop 2, ...
So far I have managed to plot the graph and use cumtrapz to work out the total area enclosed within all the loops. This total area was 2167.25 (J). But I am not sure how I can work out what the area is within each individual loop. If anyone could work out what the area is within each individual loop I would highly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.
data = xlsread('results.xlsx');
x = xlsread('results.xlsx', 'results', 'AK:AK');
y = xlsread('results.xlsx', 'results', 'AJ:AJ');

figure;
plot(x, y, 'k-');
xlabel('Displacement (m)', 'FontSize', 14);
ylabel('Load (N)', 'FontSize', 14);


% Calculate area under all loops
area_under_curves = cumtrapz(x, y);

% Total area under all loops
total_area = area_under_curves(end);

% Display the total area under all loops
fprintf('Total area under all loops: %.2f\n', total_area);


If you click "enter image description here" you can see the graph.

If you plot the load and displacement separately, you'll see that they both show peaks and valleys. Detect the peaks and valleys, segment your curves and calculate the area for each loop.

One way would be to detect the edges of all loops using function boundary, and then you can get are within theese edge coordinates using function area and polyshape. But if you need to get the area of each individual loop. then you need to cut all the rows into segemtns. Now this is tricky part, becouse it depends on how are the cycles connected. It would be much more easier if you could upload a smaller part of the dataset, then me or somebody else could to this loop segmentation. Getting the area of each loop is super easy afterwards.
